# Getter using references and returning a constant variable

Tags: constants, getter

I have the following question: I define a class containing a private vector of (my) objects - i.e.:

```
vector<myOtherClass> myVector;
```

Then I would like to define a getter method which should not copy all objects saved in the vector. Thus I am always using references:

```
vector<myOtherClass> &getMyVector() const {
    return (myVector);
}
```

The “const” means that I can only read the member variables in this method. But what should I do if I want that the returning variable is a constant - in particular what difference is between the three following possibilities (sometimes, the compiler allows me only to use one of them):

```
const vector<myOtherClass> &getMyVector() const {
    return (myVector);
}
```

,

```
vector<myOtherClass> const &getMyVector() const {
    return (myVector);
}
```

and

```
const vector<myOtherClass> const &getMyVector() const {
    return (myVector);
}
```

Comment: P.S. - one related question: What is the difference if I use pointers.